# Aspose - The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly. in mscrm

Tags: dynamics-crm, licensing, aspose, aspose.words

I am running a job combining Dynamics CRM that uses Aspose to create pdf files, everything was working fine until suddenly I got the error :

> The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly.

At the current moment in my dev environment everything works fine only In my qa environment I get that exception. I checked the path I use it is correct. I tried to put the licence near the dll file in a specific file etc'... still I get this msg, what is the solution in my case?

My function:

```
 public void EnsureAsposeLicenseIsSet()
        {
            if (!AsposeLicenseWasSet)
            {
                lock ("EnsureAsposeLicenseIsSet")
                {
                    if (!AsposeLicenseWasSet)
                    {
                        License wordLicense = new License();                     
                        wordLicense.SetLicense(GetConfigByKey("Asposelicence"));
                        AsposeLicenseWasSet = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is this in a plugin? What version of CRM? Is it on-prem or online? Are you using ILMerge to include the Aspose library? It could be that the plugin is registered outside the sandbox in DEV but in the sandbox in QA.

Comment: @Aron It's with job and it's on premise I'm not using ilmerge

Comment: You can have just single library within plugin - so I'm wondering how you're referencing aspose - which is another library. Do you have it registered in GAC locally perhaps ? While on QA you don't ?

Comment: Are you sure the process running your code has the necessary permissions to access the license?

Answer (score 1):

Include the Aspose license file as an **Embedded resource** instead, and it will work.